# How can I tell Eagle to not export a 'part' to Bill of Materials?

Tags: eaglecad, bom

I (as I believe many of you do too) have many parts that are not actually required for assembly but are on the schematic. (Some holes, logos, stamps, references, etc..).

Whenever I export a BOM I have to manually remove these parts from the list.

Is there a way to tell Eagle to always not export these parts to the BOM? On the package, device or symbol editor for example?

Comment: I always suggest putting the parts on the BOM, but change the value or create a field titled "Notes" or something similar and type in "DNP" for "Do Not Populate"

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen such an option and I'm not sure whether it exists, but I can think of a simple programmatic solution. Devise a prefix for the names of the parts that you don't want in the BOM, e.g. if a part was "JP1", rename it to "NAN_JP1" (where NAN stands for "Not Actually Needed", but of course you can use any prefix you like). They'll be sorted together in the BOM, so both manual filtering is easy, or you can go for a programmatic approach using tools like `grep` (`grep -v NAN_ «your_bom_file»`).

This is not what you asked for, but hope it helps :)